# url estatica para mi proyecto php

Tags: php, css, html5, php7

Estoy empezando un proyecto en `PHP`, pero no se como hacer para que me quede en variable.

He visto una que dice desde el servidor local colocando local host, por ejemplo esto:

```
$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

Me da eso mismo local host entonces quiero hacer una ruta estática pero así con variable tengo un archivo `CSS` que quiero incluirlo ahí en un `link` con `href`, pero me enrede lo hice así:

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$host;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $host ?>/obtenerurl/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h5>superior</h5>
```

Obtener `url` es el nombre del proyecto , pero al igual no me funciona el estilo que hice por que no me encuentra la ruta, no se como configurar esa ruta

Comment: Si tu problema es que no encuentra la ruta del archivo CSS, entonces publicá el código desde donde lo estás haciendo así lo vemos.

Comment: Primero que nada esto `$host/'obtenerurl/estilo.css'` es un error de sintaxis. Debería ser `$host . '/obtenerurl/estilo.css'`. Segundo, si vas a indicar el "dominio" en las rutas a los recursos, es necesario que antepongas `//`, por ejemplo, 'href="//localhost/obtenerurl/estilo.css"'. Aún así, para este caso, considero que no deberías hacerlo ya que podes omitirlo y simplemente usar `/`, para indicar que el `path` es desde la raíz del dominio. es decir, `href="/obtenerurl/estilo.css'"`

Comment: hola amigo ya edit la pregunta como tengo el codigo

Comment: si amigo la variable que declare host me retorna esto 'href="//localhost, mi problema es que no se como incorporar esa bariable con el resto de la ruta si hago manual localhost..... y la ruta si me da pero el lio, es que no se como ponerlo junto con mi variable para no colocar local host si no una variable que me englobe

Answer (score 0):

Eso normalmente se hace en una constante, en un fichero de configuración, ya que puedes tener tu aplicación en un directorio fuera del acceso público. En tu caso y para no complicarte, podrías hacer que te muestre el protocolo que estás usando, el host, y la ruta así:

```
$url = "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "s" : "") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

donde $url será la variable que guarde tu host y tu ruta. Pruébalo a ver.

Comment: Como detalle, cambia también el http por el valor de la variable $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], así también lo haces dinámico para el http o https y no necesitas ese if. El puerto puede cambiar también por configuración, así que no puedes asegurar el 443 si lo quieres hacer dinamico

Comment: href="<?php echo $ruta . 'estilo.css' ?>">  con esta me funciono, pero lo extra{o es que si llamo el header  en otro archivo se pierde el diseño no entiendo por que

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero declarar una constante utilizando `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` en caso que quieras utilizar rutas absolutas e incluirla en un archivo para su uso en todos el proyecto:

Por ejemplo, en un archivo `config.php` defines lo siguiente:

```
defined("CSS_PATH") or define('CSS_PATH', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/nombre_proyecto/css/');
```

Luego, en tus archivos donde quieras cargar tus archivos de hojas de estilo, incluyes el archivo ´config.php´ donde tienes definida la constante:

```
<?php

include_once('config.php');

?>
```

Por último, hacer referencia a esa constante:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH;?>/obtenerurl/estilo.css">
```

Espero que te sirva.